# Inserir em array

Tags: php

Eu estou tentando ao fazer um sistema onde, o usuário seleciona os produtos e vai adicionando em uma lista, sem que a pagina seja recarregada novamente. A principio eu fiz com que a pagina não fosse recarregada novamente usando `ajax`, porém estou com dois problema, o primeiro é que os campos dos dados sobre o cliente são apagados sem que eu queria, os dados que deveriam ser apagados seria apenas os do produto, e o segundo é que não consigo pensar em um jeito de inserir os dados em uma lista e mostra-los posteriormente em uma tabela separando, nome, preço e o total.

**Ajax**

```
$("#adicionar").click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Model/resultado.php',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $(".table").append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**Formulário de pedidos**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <!-- Nome -->
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <!-- Legenda -->
        <label for="nomeProduto" class="label label-primary">Nome do Produto</label>

        <!-- Campo -->
        <select class="form-control text-center" name="produto" id="nomeProduto" tabindex="2" title="Nome do Produto" onfocus="completarCamposProdutos();">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php
                foreach ($produtos as $produto)
                {
                    ?>
                        <!-- Opcoes -->
                        <option
                            value="<?= $produto['id'] ?>"
                            data-preco="<?= $produto["valorVenda"] ?>"
                            data-estoque="<?= $produto['quantidadeAtual'] ?>">
                            <?= $produto['nomeProduto'] ?>
                        </option>
                    <?php
                }
              ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Valor Unitario -->
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <!-- Legenda -->
        <label for="valorUnitario" class="label label-primary">Valor Unitário</label>

        <!-- Campo -->
        <input type="text" name="valorUnitario" id="valorUnitario" class="form-control text-center" readonly="" title="Valor Unitario" placeholder="Valor Unitario">
    </div>

    <!-- Quantidade -->
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <!-- Legenda -->
        <label for="quantidade" class="label label-primary">Quantidade</label>

        <!-- Campo -->
        <input type="text" name="quantidade" id="quantidade" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Quantidade" title="Quantidade" tabindex="3">
    </div>

    <!-- Total -->
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <!-- Legenda -->
        <label for="total" class="label label-primary">Total</label>

        <!-- Campo -->
        <input type="text" name="totalUnitario" id="total" class="form-control text-center" title="Total" placeholder="Total" readonly="">
    </div>

    <!-- Restante estoque -->
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <!-- Legenda -->
        <label for="estoque" class="label label-primary">Estoque restante</label>

        <!-- Campo -->
        <input type="text" name="estoque" id="estoque" class="form-control text-center" title="Estoque Restante" placeholder="Estoque Restante" readonly="">
    </div>

    <!-- Cadastrar -->
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-success form-control" id="adicionar" tabindex="4">OK</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Carregando ajax -->
    <script language="javascript" src="../Util/JavaScript/AdicionarProdutosEmPedidos.js"></script>
</div>
```

**Resultado.php**

```
<?php
    // Requerindo arquivos
    require_once "../Util/Seguranca/ControleAcesso.php";

    // Funcao que protege a logica contra acesso nao autorizado
    ProtegePagina();

    // Recebendo parametros por post
    $nomeProduto = $_POST['produto'];
    $valorUnitario = $_POST['valorUnitario'];
    $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
    $total = $_POST['totalUnitario'];
```

Comment: Geralmente em sistemas assim o pessoal faz uso de `$_SESSION`

Comment: mas isso não iria acarretar o recarregamento da pagina?

Comment: Não necessariamente, pode enviar os dados e inserir na `$_SESSION` usando `ajax`

Comment: a session me parece fazer sentido, mas conforme o usuário for adicionando produtos a lista, como eu criaria sessions pra isso, teria que ser algo meio automatico e que possa ser salvo em um banco de dados posteriormente

Comment: Não seria criar sessions, no plural, você trabalharia com os dados criados em uma unica session

Comment: Eu nunca usei session dessa forma, to meio perdido, pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Põe a session na página do formulário e session na página php que é chamada pelo ajax. E crie também um botão de retirar da lista que retira da página com javascript e com ajax tb retira da lista que está numa variável de sessão.

Comment: Eu devo estar fazendo algo errado, porque não funcionou, coloquei uma session armazenando o nome do produto e outra na tabela que deveria mostrar o nome da mesma, quando executei o ajax, nada aparece